# Getting position of tapped cell(accessory button) in table view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

How can I get exact y position of cell, when user tapped accessory button in table view?
I mean not index position in table, but y coordinate of this row.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CGRect rectInTableView = [tableView rectForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

Will give you the coordinates within the tableView's content. If you want to convert to the parent view's coordinates, use

```
 CGRect rect = [tableView convertRect:rectInTableView toView:[tableView superview]];
```

In addition to the previous line.